# Order posts by month - in custom taxonomy template

Tags: custom-taxonomy, date-time

I'm trying to show all posts posted under the month, so

2012

### December

post 1
post 2

### November

post 1
post 2

The posts are to appear under my custom taxonomy template, so taxonomy-pubyear.php and I'm able to retrive all the posts for that term using the basic loop.  If I add get_the_year('F') in the loop then the same month will be displayed repeatedly but I need it displayed once and have all the corresponding posts show up under it, any help with this would be appreciated.

Note: If I have post published under the same day, month and year then the above get_the_year('F') will show the month and display those posts below it, i want that functionality but without having to use the same published date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the current month in a variable and check it for each post, only output it when it changes:

```
$current_month = '';

while( have_posts() ):
    the_post();

    $this_month = get_the_time( 'F' );

    if( $this_month != $current_month ){
        $current_month = $this_month;
        echo $current_month;
    }

    the_title();

endwhile;
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks a million. Just out of curiosity, why not use the get_the_date() function instead?

Comment: you could use `get_the_date` here, it would work the same. I'm in the habit of using `get_the_time` because it's a bit more flexible, as you can also pass a post id where `get_the_date` will only work with the global `$post` object.